# Making a simple Twitter API call

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth

Hey guys I've been looking for a good resource other than the official twitter documentation that would fully show me how to utilize their API.  The basic request is easy enough, I've formatted these before.  My problem is that I get a cross-site-scripting error, and I think it has to do with a lack of OAuth authentication in my app but their resources are saturated with so much information it doesn't explain it simply.  Can anyone show me how to set up a simple API call to make a tweet or point me to a resource?

Answer (score 1):

[Hello.js](https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js/) is a client side OAuth library and has a twitter specific module.

Comment: I'm testing locally so I have no domain to register.